# How to use lib file to make another lib in Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want to make a lib file which is using another my lib file. I've tried various combinations in makefile to do linking, but sometimes it asking that linking command ignored or not warning but crashes when I'm trying to use code from libs. My makefile looks like this:

```
SRC = a.cpp b.cpp c.cpp etc.
OBJ = $(SRC:.cpp=.o)
OUT = ./libHTTPServer.a
INCLUDES := -I/home/myuser/Development/boost_1_51_0 \
            -I/home/myuser/Development/HTTPServers/Prot
CCFLAGS = -g
CCC = g++
LIBS = -L/home/myuser/Development/boost_1_51_0/buildedlibs/lib -lm
LDFLAGS = -g
.SUFFIXES: .cpp
.cpp.o:
    $(CCC) $(INCLUDES) $(CCFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -lc libProt.a
$(OUT): $(OBJ)
    ar rcs $(OUT) $(OBJ)

depend: dep
dep:
    makedepend -- $(CCFLAGS) -- $(INCLUDES) $(SRC)
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ) $(OUT)
```

Comment: What command do you use to build the new file *without* Make?

Comment: Did you try `ar` command? That's the one I am aware of, for making a library `.a` out of `.o` files.

Comment: anishsane I'm using ar to make my second lib file

ar rcs $(OUT) $(OBJ)

Answer (score 0):

You can't link libraries to your static library that you're creating. A static library is just a collection of object files packed into an archive.

If libProt is something that you produce yourself and have object files for you could perhaps add them in your `ar` command to "combine" these two static libraries.